# How can i make a reset command to restart my discord.js bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to make a command so when I do !reset it will reboot/restart the bot. I am using Discord.js v12.

This bot is a simple moderation bot for a server so I just want a quick command to fix errors that require a quick restart without going into Heroku and restart it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd imagine you'd need to call the Heroku API to restart the service.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#dyno-restart

Answer (score 0):

To restart your bot you shall destroy the [Client](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client) and call the [login()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=login) method.

```js
client.destroy();
client.login(process.env.token);
```

Example:

```
if (command === "reset") {
    if (message.author.id !== "Your ID Here") return false;
    message.reply("Resetting...");
    client.destroy();
    client.login(process.env.token);
};
```

Comment: If the user added code they would need to restart using heroku, destroying the client and relogging in won't help, either way destroying the client isn't recommended